# IF IF statement with a Ternary (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, ternary

How can I turn the following statement into a Ternary.

```
if($.isNumber(arg1))
{
    if($.isNumber(arg2))
    {
        // something
    }
}
```

I know how to do an IF / ELSE with a Ternary statement like:

```
var a = $.isNumber(arg1) ? arg1 : $.isNumber(arg2) ? arg2 : undefined
```

for example.

not sure how to do an IF / IF / ELSE though.

Any help?

Comment: Actually would I just do this:

var a = $.isNumber(arg1) && $.isNumber(arg2) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = $.isNumber(arg1) && $.isNumber(arg2) ? "something" : "nothing";
```

Comment: Thank you, I realised that might have been the code seconds after I posted :S
Thanks for the help